# What Minecraft sound setting are minecarts in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was on a map, and it required a lot of minecart use. This was really loud, but I don't want to turn down my overall volume. I go to sound settings, and I find that nothing works! Minecarts don't fall under any categories...
So how do I turn down my minecart volume without turning down my overall volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, nvm. I just realized that since minecarts are entities, they turn down with the "friendly creatures" setting. #embarrassed

Comment: Nothing to be embarassed about, it was a good question.

Comment: That is the weirdest place for them to be. No need to be embarrassed. TBH, Thank you for answering my own question about it.